# Check status of MS Teams within flow

Tags: power-automate

In my PowerAutomate Flow, a survey is sent to an array of email addresses via MS Teams.
In the PowerAutomate 1:1 chat, the respondent can choose from several predefined answers.
After a waiting period of 30 minutes (or as soon as everyone has voted, whichever comes first), an email is sent to all participants of the survey with the results.

Now my survey always runs into the 30-minute timeout clause when surveyed participants are out of office.

Is there a way to check the status of MS Teams of the users within the array so that only participants in the company network are queried who do not have the status "offline"?

I have already tried the possibilities with (a) "HTTP request" as well as with (b) "get mail tips for a mailbox" and the "out-of-office" message stored by the user.
However, these are not possible (a) or run into the same error if no note is stored (b).

Do you have any ideas?

My example for (b):
[image]

Comment: Did you try the Graph API "presence"? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/presence-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http With the HTTP connector and an Azure app registration with Presence.Read.All it should work. But you said it's not possible, why?